# PHPExcel load() function reset the connection

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am using [PHPExcel](http://www.codeplex.com/PHPExcel) version 1.7.9 for reading .xlsx file.

For loading I am using

```
if(file_exists($path)) {
  $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($path);
  ...
```

Its running in desired manner for some file (running good for about 500KB file having 1000 rows and 103 cols) but for larger file (about 4000 rows and 103 cols). the connection is getting reset.

I have already updated memory limit and max_execution time but of no effect.

Comment: SO what do your webserver logs say?

Comment: Thanks Mark, but logs are not indicating any errors other then ' It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings'

Comment: The probability is that it's either running out of memory, or hitting a timeout; but unless the logs give you something to work with it's almost impossible to say with any certainty

Comment: Ya, I also think so but is there are limit of cells, I think I have read it somewhere

Comment: Within the limit of PHP Memory, and allowing for cell caching, PHPExcel limits cells to the same limits as MS Excel itself (ie. 65,536 rows by 256 columns for BIFF files, 1,048,576 rows by 16,384 columns for OfficeOpenXML files)... I'd love to know where you read otherwise, because whoever wrote it is wrong

Comment: Thank you Mark, that's very nice library you gave to us. I wish, I have some kind of memory or timeout error instead of 'You connection is reset', I cant even do the exception handling on this :(